# PHP: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: php, mediawiki

In my server (Newly launched) when I am trying to upgrade MediaWiki. I am getting the following error.

> php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory

But when i check in server i can find the libssl.so

> 183~# cd /pkg/products/httpd/httpd_2.2.19a_RH5_64/php/lib/ 183lib# ls
>
> -la total 72556 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Sep 16 15:43 . drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Sep 16 11:37 ..
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52439406 Aug 18 08:31 libclntsh.so.11.1
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1786841 Aug 18 09:06 libcrypto.so.0.9.8
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Aug 18 08:26 libmysqlclient.so
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5264820 Aug 18 08:26 libmysqlclient.so.16
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5264820 Aug 18 08:26 libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7898628 Aug 18 08:32 libnnz11.so
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   539497 Aug 18 09:03 libpng14.so.14
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   539497 Aug 18 09:03 libpng14.so.14.4.0
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   365454 Aug 18 09:05 libssl.so.0.9.8 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Sep 16 11:37 php

183 lib# pwd
/pkg/products/httpd/httpd_2.2.19a_RH5_64/php/lib

In server PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: May  9 2011 11:39:53) version is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the libraries installed in a non standard location.

If this is the case, it could be that php simply doesn't know where to look for the libraries it needs. Try setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to that path before launching php, if you're running it from command line. For example in bash:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pkg/products/httpd/httpd_2.2.19a_RH5_64/php/lib
```

If this works you could add that path to system configuration. I don't know other distributions but Debian keeps the library paths in the file /etc/ld.so.conf or in the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
You will probably be able to find a similar file in your /etc folder